# I know how it's done with jQuery -- How to make request for JSONP using Mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

I am used to using jQuery, and it works great for this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "someURL",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    success: function (msg) {},
    error: function (msg) {}
});
```

** NOTE:
When I omitted **jsonp: 'jsonp'**, this error was displayed in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

What I tried after reading the Mootools documentation:

**Attempt:**

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: "someURL",
    onComplete: function (msg) {},
    onFailure: function (msg) {}
}).get();
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It is displaying that Response.JSONP is not a function. When I attempt to use JSON:

**Attempt:**

```
new Request.JSON({
    url: "someURL",
    onComplete: function (msg) {},
    onFailure: function (msg) {}
}).get();
```

**Error:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.theirsite.com. Origin http://yoursite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Which is a cross-domain access issue using Ajax, which is why I am using JSONP.

I am very confused about the

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Error, and I don't understand why it works with jQuery.

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: instead og `get()` try `send()`

Comment: Yes, I tried that initially

Comment: I am still receiving the error: 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function, for Request.JSONP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mootools, JSONP is not built-in to the Core library. You'll have to [build JSONP into another javascript file using the More Builder](http://mootools.net/more/) in order for it to be available to use.

As you probably realized, the syntax for a `Request.JSONP` call using mootools is identical to a call using `Request.JSON`. Also, ensure that the remote listener listens for a `callback` parameter, and appends it to the output.

e.g.

**index.php**

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://absolute/url/to/endpoint.php',
    onSuccess: function(result) {
        console.log(result);    // should output 'bar' to the console
    }
}).get({
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

**endpoint.php**

```
echo $_REQUEST['callback'] . '(' . $_REQUEST['foo'] . ');';
```

Comment: I really wish I could select two correct answers. You found the reason why the JSONP method was undefined, and Andrew found the reason why I was getting the Unexpected Token Error. Thank you both so much

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll upvote @Andrew's answer to even it out :)

Answer (score 4):

The following option for `$.ajax` sets the callback function name to `jsonp`:

```
jsonp: 'jsonp'
```

I think you need to specify the `callbackKey` option in a similar way:

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: "someURL",
    onComplete: function (msg) {},
    onFailure: function (msg) {},
    callbackKey: 'jsonp'
}).get();
```

Comment: I really wish I could select two correct answers. You and Julian are both right